# Rank and generators of elliptic curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

I need to calculate the rank and the generators of the elliptic curve

```
            [0,1,0,-15662264585,746984342506759]
```

that is,
$$
y^2 = x^3 + x^2 -15662264585 x + 746984342506759.
$$

Comment: Why this curve?  I'm guessing you meant [0, 1, 0, -15662264585, 746984342506759] (missing the third coefficient 0), because this curve has  28 pairs of integral points with x < 10^8, which generate a group of rank 8, and that kind of thing almost never happens at random . . .

Comment: I see that this question has been put on hold on the grounds
"unclear what you're asking".  It is by now clear that the intended
elliptic curve was $y^2 = x^3 + x^2 -15662264585 x + 746984342506759$
(using the standard notation $[a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_6]$ [sic] for
the curve with extended Weierstrass form
$y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6$). 
So I'm editing the question and voting to reopen.
This still begs the question of *why* this curve is of interest
(yes, rank $\geq 8$ is unusual, but we've known for some time how to generate
infinitely many such curves) and how the OP found it.

Answer (score 13):

For the record, **mwrank** eventually confirmed that this curve
$$
E : y^2 = x^3 + x^2 - 15662264585 x + 746984342506759
$$
has rank $8$, as suggested by the calculation of integral points
($28$ pairs $(x,\pm y)$ with $x < 10^8$, but all in the same rank-8 group)
and corroborated by the global root number of $+1$ (which under the
parity conjecture implies that the rank is even, so if the rank exceeds $8$
there must be at least two further independent generators that do not
contribute to the list of small integral points).

Shortly after this question was posed, I went to
**germain.math.harvard.edu** and set John Cremona's program **mwrank**
on this curve $E$.  Some hours later, **mwrank** had found six independent
points while

```
Looking for Type 2 quartics:
Trying positive a from 1 up to 70218 (square a first...)
```

but then seemed to go into hibernation after announcing it was

```
Trying positive a from 1 up to 70218 (...then non-square a)
```

Still, there was nothing else happening on **germain**, so I let the
process continue, and then forgot about it for some time.
Recently I checked again and found that the program had
completed the calculation three weeks(!) later,
finishing its report with

```
Generator 1 is [78271:-777724:1]; height 9.80876524759791
Generator 2 is [78077:294276:1]; height 10.1492862271008
Generator 3 is [10092319809:21622801863508:2197]; height 19.7776896372427
Generator 4 is [4284948894:19048354703:54872]; height 18.1180101559044
Generator 5 is [6394749009:2154538281608:35937]; height 18.3383217073227
Generator 6 is [8109376287:42485008616:103823]; height 17.8505437330629
Generator 7 is [5638548716266233736152:-615800483663476330089571:98759759636551168]; height 37.1133372519458
Generator 8 is [73421481:29109699172:343]; height 15.0939038726812

Regulator = 6202462.51465316

The rank and full Mordell-Weil basis have been determined unconditionally.
```

The full output is
[here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/mo266489.mwop).

There must be faster ways of determining the rank and Mordell-Weil group
of an elliptic curve with coefficients, rank, and generators of this size,
but the fact that **mwrank** was able to do it in three weeks might still
be an interesting data point about this kind of computation.

The question at the end of my comment still stands:

> This still begs the question of *why* this curve is of interest
>   (yes, rank $\geq 8$ is unusual, but we've known for some time how to generate
>   infinitely many such curves) and how the OP found it.

Comment: Sorry, pet peeve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question

Comment: Well the phrase "petitio principii" hardly made sense in Latin,
and its translation as "beg the question" makes even less sense
in English for a form of circular reasoning.  So it's natural for the phrase to be
used as if it were "beg for the question".  By now even Merriam-Webster
recognizes "to elicit a question logically as a reaction or response"
as the primary sense of the phrase, with secondary sense
"to pass over or ignore a question by assuming it to be established or settled".  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beg%20the%20question

Answer (score 2):

As another data point, Magma was able to find 8 generators in about 15 seconds under the assumption of GRH.

```
SetClassGroupBounds("GRH");
E := EllipticCurve([0,1,0,-15662264585,746984342506759]);
Generators(E);
```

Output:

```
[ (29182241521/369664 : -357905489312311/224755712 : 1), (100099 : -13497788 : 1), (72219471 : 613734879724 : 1), (162669513/1369 : 1202545309672/50653 : 1), (52676723 : 382319900340 : 1), (-15653710/121 : -32820199443/1331 : 1), (20638562/169 : -56252791245/2197 : 1), (56710535981/722500 : -677498563801629/614125000 : 1) ]
true true

Calculations are restricted to 120 seconds.
Input is limited to 50000 bytes.
Running Magma V2.24-1.
Seed: 2015558728; Total time: 15.919 seconds; Total memory usage: 149.22MB.
```